# Logging level not carried over to other modules

Tags: python, logging

According to the docs and a ton SO answers and the like, "all you have to do" to do logging across multiple modules is set the logger up in your main file and then use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

But this is not true. If you do that the logging level will not get carried over so you need an additional line in every file you have `logger.setLevel(...)`. Simple example:

`test.py`

```
import logging
from test2 import bla

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def main():
    logger.info('main info')
    bla()

main()
```

`test2.py`

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def bla():
    logger.info('info')
    logger.debug('debug')
```

If I run `test.py`, nothing from `test2.py` will be printed.

Is there something else one has to do in the initial setup that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing is printed is that you didn't set the level of the root logger, so it defaulted to `WARNING`. If you replace with `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` then you should get `INFO` and `DEBUG` messages from `test2.py`.